# Connection error for requests and BeautifulSoup4. Last night my code worked and I haven't changed anything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I'm writing code that performs web scraping. I'm trying to get HTML code from the Cambridge dictionary website, but an error message pops up. I would really appreciate it if you can teach me the reason for the error and the solution to this problem.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    



def checkWord(word):
    url_top = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/"
    url = url_top + word

    headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

    headers.update(
        {
            'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0',
        }       
    )

    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 
    check = soup.find("title")
    boolean = check.string

    
    if boolean == "Cambridge English Dictionary: Meanings & Definitions":
        return False
    else:
        return True

word = "App"
checkWord(word)
```

However, error occured at `html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text`

Error message is shown below--

```
Exception has occurred: ConnectionError
('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Most likely you’ve been banned for hitting the site using a bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is worrking fine all the times. Most likely the problem is your local internet that's why it  may be temporarily or check your internet connection

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
def checkWord(word):
    url_top = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/"
    url = url_top + word

    headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

    headers.update(
        {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        }       
    )

    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 
    check = soup.find("title").text
    print(check)


word = "App"
checkWord(word)
```

**Output:**

```
APP | meaning, definition in Cambridge English Dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the remote host banned you. If you still can open the website from your computer with a web browser try to change user agent to something like this:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: While your answer may be right, it encourages OP to continue spamming the domain using their bot. I’d advise you to delete your answer.